# Android Studio - Route all audio from phone (calls, music player, etc.) through App

Tags: java, android, android-studio, audio, libpd

I've made an app in Android Studio which is essentially a parametric EQ with some additional features. 
The app takes signal from the microphone source (whether the built-in mic or external mic). The signal is then passed through biquad filters and out to the speakers/earphones. I used LibPb to handle the signal processing.

Now, I want all the audio that would be coming out the speakers to be routed through the app.
In other words, any music playing or calls, I want the audio to also be passed through the filters in my app.

I have tried to find articles/resources on this topic but haven't found much.
I'm guessing that it can be done via [Audio Focus](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html) or [Media Router](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRouter.html) or something along those lines, but I cant figure it out!!

Firstly, is this possible?

Secondly, any code or hints as to how to go about it?

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: You can't  Especially not calls.

Comment: I found this article which addresses the issue somewhat.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329690/how-to-control-background-music-from-my-android-app
Is there any documentation which confirms that this cannot be done?